# Store JSON request in DynamoDB with Lambda

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have an http request in my Lambda function that returns a json. I'm using node.js. I want to save that json as an object in my DynamoDB table.

```
const http = require('https')
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({region: "eu-west-1"});

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    return httprequest().then((data) => {
        //Parse JSON to objects

        // in this case not neccessary because it's already parsed.
        // data is already object

        // var arr_from_json = JSON.parse(data);

        //add Item to DynamoDB
        var params = {
            TableName: 'json',
            Item: {
                date: Date.now(),
                answer: data.answer,
                forced: data.forced,
                image: data.image
            }
        };

        var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

        docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            else console.log(data);
        });

        // Respond with JSON
        const response = {

            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        };
        return response;
    });
};

function httprequest() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const options = {
            host: 'yesno.wtf',
            path: '/api',
            port: 443,
            method: 'GET'
        };
        const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
            if (res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode >= 300) {
                return reject(new Error('statusCode=' + res.statusCode));
            }
            var body = [];
            res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                body.push(chunk);
            });
            res.on('end', function () {
                try {
                    body = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(body).toString());
                } catch (e) {
                    reject(e);
                }
                resolve(body);
            });
        });
        req.on('error', (e) => {
            reject(e.message);
        });
        // send the request
        req.end();
    });
}
```

JSON

> {"answer":"no","forced":false,"image":"https://yesno.wtf/assets/no/8-5e08abbe5aacd2cf531948145b787e9a.gif"}

However, it's not storing the object in DynamoDB. What can I do differently? Is the section for storing in DynamoDB correct in the first place?

Comment: Does your lambda have a role with the `AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess` policy (or a custom one with write access) attached?

Comment: @Danziger Yes, I have a role with read and write permission.

Comment: And do you see any alarm or error in CloudWatch? Maybe it would be worth adding some `console.log()` in your code to make sure it's actually reaching `docClient.put()`. Also, you could try changing that to `const data = await docClient.put(...).promise()` and only sending the response back once the DynamoDB operation has finished, but that should not make any difference here  I guess.

Comment: @Danziger Thanks for taking your time! I just put a console.log(data) before the line `docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {` and it's shown in CloudWatch.

Comment: @Danziger Might the problem be that I use the put-function in a return-statement `return httprequest().then((data) => {` ? If so, how could I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I assume that the table exists and that the lambda has the right permissions. Otherwise you would be getting a `Requested resource not found` or `not authorized to perform: dynamodb:PutItem` error, respectively.

You are calling `docClient.put(...)` but then just return a response from the lambda without waiting for DynamoDB's response. If you wait for DynamoDB's response before sending a response back, it works as expected, as you can see in the example below using [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await):

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

// There's no need to re-instantiate this on each request:
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: 'eu-west-1', apiVersion: 'latest' });    

function httprequest() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve({
                answer: 'no',
                forced: false,
                image: 'https://yesno.wtf/assets/no/8-5e08abbe5aacd2cf531948145b787e9a.gif',
            });
        }, 2000);
    })
}

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    try {
        const data = await httprequest();

        const params = {
            Item: {
                date: Date.now(),
                answer: data.answer,
                forced: data.forced,
                image: data.image
            },

            TableName: 'json'
        };

        await docClient.put(params).promise();

        console.log('Document inserted.');

        return JSON.stringify(data);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);

        return err;
    }
};
```

That being said, intuitively I'd say if `docClient.put(...)` is reached then the document should get inserted into DynamoDB anyway, but it looks like that's not the case, at least not when using a callback. However, if you replace that with `docClient.put(params).promise()`, the document will be inserted, even if you are not waiting for DynamoDB's response. `docClient.put(params)` alone won't work either.

I think that's a bit confusing/counter-intuitive, so I have created this other question to find out more about why that works the way it works:

[Why values are not inserted into DynamoDB unless calling `.promise()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61738467/why-values-are-not-inserted-into-dynamodb-if-the-lambda-returns-without-waiting)

Comment: @incnnu Check this. There are a few things I would do differently, but if the execution is reaching `docClient.put(params)`, then I don't see why the document would not be inserted in DynamoDB.

Comment: @Danzinger Thanks so much, your code is working perfectly! And thanks for the helpful tips! Yes, I tried the put-function above the line `return httprequest().then((data) => {` and that would actually store the item in DynamoDB, but putting it underneath that line does not work.

Comment: @incnnu I have updated the answer with an explanation of what works and what doesn't work, but as I still find that counter-intuitive, I have also linked another question I have just created to find out why it works the way it works.